# Example of ordered sets that are not order-isomorphic

Tags: lattice-orders, integer-lattices

**Let $X$ and $Y$ be two ordered sets, each of cardinality $6$. I need an example of two such sets which are not order isomorphic.**

I tried with $(X,\le_X)=(\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\},\le_X)$ and $(Y,\le_Y)=\{\pm1,\pm4,\pm9\},\le_Y)$ and defined $f:X\to Y$ by $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in X$ and $\le$ is 'less than or equal to'.

Since $f$ is not surjective, so not bijective and consequently not order-isomorphic.

Is my explanation ok? If not, where did I make mistake? And if my answer is correct, is there any more convincing example other than this?

Comment: I don't understand the reason for downvoting. Can you please explain?

Comment: Those posets you defined are indeed order-isomorphic. (It is apparent from your definition that you're using the 'usual' order, i.e., $x\leq y$ iff $y-x$ is non-negative.) You function is not an order-isomorphism, but $g:X\to Y$ given by $g(2)=4$, $g(-2)=-4$, $g(3)=9$, $g(-3)=-9$ and $g(x)=x$, for $x \in \{-1,1\}$ is an order-isomorphism.

Comment: Meanwhile, it's very easy to come up with non-isomorphic posets with the same cardinal (finite or infinite): for a given set $X$, consider the posets $(X,=)$ (an anti-chain), and $(X,\leq)$ where $\leq$ is another arbitrary order relation; for example, making $(X,\leq)$ a chain.

Comment: @amrsa I thought whether a function is order isomorphic or not would be decided according to my choice of defining the function.

Comment: @amrsa what can be  this $X$ with $6$ elements? In an antichain, all elements are equal and so how can they be distinct?

Comment: All elements are different. If the order is equality, then each element is only related to itself (by reflexivity). That means that in the Hasse diagram, the poset is represented by six nodes with no connections.

Comment: @amrsa I am not able make this answer. It'll be so kind of you if you post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [$318$ non-isomorphic posets with $6$ elements](https://oeis.org/A000112).

To give just two of them, consider the six-element chain and the six-element anti-chain:
take the set $X = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$ and define two order relations:

- The first is the equality, that is two elements are related iff they are equal (it's the same element). It's easy to check this is a partial order relation (just check the defining properties). Its Hasse diagram is just a set of six nodes without any connections between them.
- The second is, for example, the order given by restricting to this set the usual order on the natural numbers: $x \leq y$ iff $y - x$ is non-negative. The Hasse diagram of this poset is given by a set of six nodes starting from node $1$, and then node $2$ above it, with the corresponding line uniting them; then node $3$, ... and so on until node $6$ (five lines uniting them).